# Unable to install SpecFlow + Excel v1.7.3 on Visual Studio 2015 with Specflow v2.4.0 already Installed

Tags: selenium-webdriver, bdd, specflow

Unable to install SpecFlow + Excel v1.7.3 on Visual Studio 2015 with SpecFlow v2.4.0 already Installed.

**Installed in VS2015:**
SpecFlow - v2.4.0,
SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic - v1.3.1

I am getting the following error when attempting to install SpecFlow Plus Excel:

```
Install-Package : Unable to find a version of 'SpecFlow' that is compatible with 'SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic 1.3.1 constraint: SpecFlow (>= 2.1.0)', 'SpecFlow.Plus.Excel.2-3-0 
1.7.3 constraint: SpecFlow (>= 2.3.2 && < 2.4.0)', 'SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation 2.4.1 constraint: SpecFlow (= 2.4.1)'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Specflow.Plus.Excel
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Is there a SpecFlow Plus Excel version which is compatible with SpecFlow v2.4.0?

Answer (score 0):

There is a pre-release package for SpecFlow+Excel that supports SpecFlow 2.4: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpecFlow.Plus.Excel.2-4-0/1.8.0-unstable035

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. I will patiently wait for the stable version. :)